# IoT Remote Desktop for Mac

Tags: pi-3, remote, windows-iot

I have a Pi3 with multiple Oses one of them of which is Window IoT Core. I see that there is a remote client for Windows but is there anything for MacOS??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not compatible with a product of Apple. Even with a Windows 7 PC you'll not be able to install the remote client. One and only possibility is Windows 10.
I would recommend you to run a virtual windows 10 on your MAC if you want to use your RPi with Windows 10 IoT.

*Hint: Microsoft automatically checks the possibility when you browse to an certain application in the store.*
[image]

Comment: yeah was just wondering if there was anything else out there. Your suggestion is a good idea though

Comment: We are still running Windows 7 on the office, you I also need the use of a virtual machine running on Windows 10. It works fine.